# use multiple sources with angucomplete-alt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm using nodejs and the angucomplete-alt directive to make an autocomplete list from two requests, each request return json data  with different fieldnames. is it possible to do such a thing  with angucomplete-alt

Comment: Did not find a way in the documentation. But that is nature since here is a question. if u are going to make two requests, how would u decide how to display these two results? Intersection or union? Or combine them before displaying? Situations could be complex. The best way may be make a new api on your server-side if u could do that.

Comment: ok , I can use one request that does two database calls, admitting that I combined data before displaying ,angucomplete has title-field attribute that has the name of the field to display , the probleme is , I have different name of fields to display  the first is User.name to search a user , and the other is Organization.Id. the big picture is that I want to be able to search for User.name and Organization.Id  in the same input text of angucomplete